# Why is my domain redirecting to a sponsored ads page when hosted by 123-reg?

Tags: domains, redirects, dns

I recently purchased a domain from 123-reg and am hosting the site on pythonanywhere.com

I tried to redirect the non-www domain to a www domain using the methods 123-reg specified but it resulted in a redirect loop, so I removed that feature. As soon as I removed it, the non-www and www domains redirect to : http://81.21.76.62/index.html?domain=clarallel.com. It's a sponsored ad page, something to do with parkingcrew?

If I prefix the domain with anything else - e.g. hi.clarallel.com I get redirected to a 123-reg site.

I'm worried that somehow my www and no-prefix domains have been hijacked. When I called 123-reg customer services, they found an A Record with a destination they didn't recognise (and which I hadn't put in).

What might be the problem with my domain

Answer (score 2):

You domain is probably parked by 123-reg, just remove all **A** and **CNAME** DNS records as they are pointing to the parked site.

- Check you DNS settings and remove all **A** and **CNAME** records.

  Now add the **CNAME** record pointing to your pythonanywhere.com APP

  Example

  *hostname:* `www` *Type*: `CNAME` *Destination CNAME:* `webapp.pythonanywhere.com`

Follow pythonanywhere.com instructions for setting up your custom domain
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/OwnDomains/

CNAME record maps your sites subdomain to another site like `webapp.pythonanywhere.com`.

A records maps your nake domain or subdomain to an IP address

Since pythonanywhere.com uses CNAME you still need to map the naked domain to you site  so set up redirection or domain forwarding under your 123-reg settings